# jQuery no me captura el evento submit de un from traído por AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, eventos

Lo que me esta ocurriendo es que mediante ajax, inserto en un div un formulario de registro, y sobre el boton de enviar formulario, trato de capturar el evento para que no se envie, y hacer la peticion por jQuery ajax con $.post pero se me envia, porque no debe de interpretar ese trozo de HTML como parte del DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('form').on('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    alert('Prevenido');
});
});
```

Aqui adjunto el formulario que cargo en el div de mi pagina principal.

```
<?php
session_start();
require("variables.php");
echo "<link href='estilos/registrarVehiculo.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>";

//Comprobar id de usuario
$query = "select id from usuarios where usuario = '$_SESSION[usuario]'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

    $id_matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
    $marca = $_POST['marca'];
    $modelo = $_POST['modelo'];
    $potencia = $_POST['potencia'];
    $combustible = $_POST['combustible'];
    $año = $_POST['año'];

    $query2 = "insert into vehiculos (id_matricula, marca, modelo, combustible, potencia, año, usuario) values ('$id_matricula', '$marca', '$modelo', '$combustible', $potencia, $año, '$fila[id]')";
    $res = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);
    if($res){
        echo "Ok";
    }else{
        echo "no ok";
    }
}
else{

echo "<form id='formulario' method='POST'>
            <label class='label'>Matrícula</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='text'  name='matricula' id='matricula' placeholder='0000AAA' maxlength='7' require></br><br/>

            <label class='label'>Marca</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='text' name='marca' id='marca' placeholder='Ford' require><br/><br/>

            <label class='label'>Modelo</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='text' name='modelo' id='modelo' placeholder='Mondeo'require><br/><br/>

            <label class='label'>Potencia</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='number' name='potencia' id='potencia' placeholder='150' min='40' max='999' size='3'><br/><br/>

            <label class='label'>Año</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='number' name='año' id='año' placeholder='2020' min='1930' max='2021' size='4'><br/><br/>

            <label class='label'>Combustible</label><br/>
                <select name='combustible' id='combustible' class='combustible'>
                    <option value='Diesel'>Diesel</option>
                    <option value='Gasolina'>Gasolina</option>
                    <option value='Electrico'>Eléctrico</option>
                </select><br/><br/>

        <input id='enviar' type='submit' name='enviar' value='Registrar Vehiculo'><br/><br/>           
    </form>
    <div id='info'></div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando añades el evento quizá este form no exista y por ese no salta el evento `submit`. 
Como lo añades dinamicamente en el DOM deberías añadir el evento de la siguiente manera.

Añades el evento sobre un elemento que siempre vaya a existir, en este caso, el documento y siempre que haya un evento submit en el form este será capturado por el elemento padre que tenga el event handler.

```
 $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
    alert('Prevenido');
 });
```